# Rust tells me that an import is unused, and then in the very same breath tells me that I should make that import

Tags: rust, import

Here's the code:

```
use crate::rooms::room::RoomInterface;

pub mod dogroom {
    pub struct R;

    impl RoomInterface for R {

    }
}
```

Here's /rooms/mod.rs:

```
pub mod room {

    //  Irrelevant stuff
    
    pub trait RoomInterface {
        // stuff
    }

    // stuff

}
```

Here's what it tells me:

[image]

I find it quite arcane that I import the very same thing it wants me to import, and yet it doesn't work.

I've tried pretty much all the permutations of the *use* keyword, and I can't make it work. What's going on?

Comment: Don't use screenshots of error messages; instead include the text of the error message so that it can be searched for by others and more easily read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`use`s are scoped to the module that imports them, not the file they are in.
Move the import into the `dogroom` module:

```
pub mod dogroom {
    use crate::rooms::room::RoomInterface;

    pub struct R;

    impl RoomInterface for R {

    }
}
```

Alternatively, you might want the `dogroom` module to re`use` everything from the parent module:

```
use crate::rooms::room::RoomInterface;
pub mod dogroom {
    use super::*;

    pub struct R;

    impl RoomInterface for R {

    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds inconvenient. But thank you.